# Mapping to existing table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I face some difficulties when attemp to map my class to existing table using Entity Framework.

My class:

```
[Table("builder_User")]
public class MobileUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("beansCount")]
    public int BeansCount { get; set; }
    [Column("bonusSum")]
    public double BonusSum { get; set; }
    [Column("facebookUsername")]
    public string FacebookUserName { get; set; }
    [Column("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Column("guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    [Column("job")]
    public string Job { get; set; }
    [Column("purchasedSum")]
    public double PurchasedSum { get; set; }
    [Column("facebookId")]
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }

}
```

My table in the database

[image]

And in `DataContext` class I have:

```
public DbSet<MobileUser> MobileUsers { get; set; }
```

But when I try to get users from the database, I get an exception

> DbContext has changed since the database was created....

When I run `add-migration` command, it generates create table command.

So what is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: Set your initializer to null `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null)` or use [NullDatabaseInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221749(v=vs.113).aspx). Note that this will stop EF from generating your db automatically so you have to generate it yourself.

 You can read on what the role of db initializers are in EF from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)

Comment: @opiants, Yes, after adding this statement it works, thanks!

Comment: @opiants You should write this as an answer to this question, so that it can be properly closed and both you and Ihor are rewarded with some points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the initializer to null by calling `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null)` or `Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<TContext>()`

By setting the initializer to null, EF will no longer verify the database schema and will no longer create the database if the schema changes. You will have to create/update the database yourself after changing the schema.

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about this approach but do not know what to call it. Is this "Code First using Fluent API"?

Comment: to be more specific: I'm wanting to write the database first, and then write the POCO's that cleanly map to the database tables. And I don't want to use a VS database project/EDMX - I'd like to write the mapping/POCO classes. But I can't  seem to find docs on that sort of practice

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific name for this exactly but this definitely isn't called "Fluent API". "Fluent API" is used to configure your schema mapping. There are 2 ways to configure EF out of the box: attribute based and Fluent API based. "Code first" is just a development workflow which is more _code-centric_ compared to the more common _designer-based_ approach. I suggest you create another question about this if you need more help.

Comment: @mmcrae Yep, you could totally do that. Code first doesn’t mean you _shouldn’t_ have a database to begin development. This is a general misconception about Code First. You could create a database, create your POCO classes then use fluent api (or attributes) to configure the context to map to your database. Personally, I prefer mapping my POCO classes using fluent api because that way my classes won't be littered with EF-specific attributes and it also means that I could decouple my POCO classes with EF.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Since you mentioned it, I actually did make a question illustrating my confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245935/how-to-manually-map-poco-to-existing-table-using-entity-framework - I think I'm getting muddled up in "Fluent API" vs "Code First" etc. stuff. Basically: I don't want to do migrations from Code-First, and I don't want edmx from DB-First - I want the POCOs to be created independent of the DB. And I'm not sure how to do that