# Manually map POCO to existing Table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have an existing database table `Movie`. Now I want to write a POCO `Movie.cs` which will map to that table. I want to have control over the mapping partially because I'm trying to learn more about EF.

The `Movie` table has 3 fields: `Title VARCHAR(255,), ReleaseDate DATETIME, Price MONEY`. What would my DbContext - derived class look like for this?

Coming from a Java/Hibernate background, I figured I would just map fields in the POCO to cols in the table, but it doesn't seem that straight forward in EntityFramework.

I only seem to find these 2 options:

1. "Code First" -> write everything in C#, then let EntityFramework generate and run migrations to constantly update and seed the DB.
2. "Database First" -> create the DB, then create a DB project in VS and generate an EDMX file which generates the POCO's for you

Both seem overly obtuse for the goal of mapping a single POCO to a single table. What am I missing? I've heard reference to "Fluent API," but that seems to lead me back to 1. or 2.

I struggled to find anything consistent in the docs that described what I was looking for.

Comment: this might help you http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-poco-ef4-a-simple-mapping/

Comment: What EF version are you using and I reckon that if you post the `Movie` table schema, you'd get a more straight answer. You don't _need_ fluent api. EF uses conventions to automatically "guess" the mapping so unless your POCO and schema doesn't match the conventions that EF use, you don't actually need fluent api.

Comment: So then how is the POCO to be associated to the table? I.e. how do I tell EF that this POCO should map to this table? Using EF 6 - but I don't think I'm looking for something specific to a version.

Comment: You just add a DbSet property of that type to your DbContext. That's it.

Comment: You maybe assume I know more than I do to begin with. For example, I'm not sure what the DbContext is / what classes I need for it to work. If you could post an answer illustrating what you mean, that'd help me a lot. The table I want to map a POCO to (without doing migrations) is very simple: `Movie` with cols: `Title VARCHAR(255), ReleaseDate DATETIME, Price MONEY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another option. You can write POCO class, map the class and disable migrations (migration involves also a metadata table called __MigrationHistory that you don't have in your database).

The class could be (using attributes to map the fields, you can use fluent interface as well)

```
class Movie {
    [PrimaryKey]
    [MaxLength(255)
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public datetime ReleaseDate {get; set;}
    public float Price {get; set;} // Or the type you prefere
}
```

For disable the migration and the model checking I usually set it in the context class (i.e. MyContext class).

```
class MyContext : DbContext {

    static MyContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<CloseUpContext>(null); // This disables model checking
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies {get; set;}


}
```

An interesting feature is CodeFirst from Database. EF generates the POCO classes starting from database. Classes often need a refactoring but is still better than writing classes from scratch.

Comment: I put `Database.SetInitializer<TestDBContext>(null);` in my constructor to disable EF generation/migration. The other thing I had to do was tell EF not to look for `Movies` table, but rather `Movie` table in the database. I did that in the `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method - which I guess you'd say is using the "Fluent API"? Thanks for your help

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards- This seems like a good approach